# References on $HZR$ theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Are there references available on $HZR$ theory ?

I found on [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HZR-theory) that this is "genuinely $\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb{Z}$-equivariant cohomology version of ordinary cohomology"

Found nothing on wikipedia, google, arxiv and here.

I thought that such a presentation could be a nice opening to real oriented cohomology theories.

Comment: It's clearly not a standard name.  I would look for anything on "twisted KR-theory", since it is supposed to classify twists for that.  Though my searches only turn up physicsy papers which aren't very clear.